# Open file depending on date c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm wondering if anyone can help out...

I've created a spreadsheet based on a 4 weekly rota which calculates all the hours worked within a 4 week period and works out the expected pay at the end of the month.

I'm now writing a desktop gadget in C# to display "Todays" and "Tomorrows" start and finish times. I'm using `GemBox.Spreadsheets` to parse the information from the xls file.

Because it's based on a 4 weekly pay structure, there will eventually be 13 different xls files for each pay period.

What I need, is to determine which file to open automatically by the C# application relative to that pay period.

i.e:

If todays date > 22/04/2017 but < 21/05/2017 open file 6.
If todays date > 21/05/2017 but < 18/06/2017 open file 7.
If todays date > 18/06/2017 but < 15/07/2017 open file 8.
etc... etc...

I just can't seem to get my head around it...

Here's my current code:

```
ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load("wages.xls");
var ws = ef.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateNow.Date;
double d = date.ToOADate();
string dateConv = d.ToString();

int objectRow, objectColumn;
ws.Cells.FindText(dateConv, false, false, out objectRow, out objectColumn);

if (objectRow == -1 || objectColumn == -1)
{
    todaysShift.Text = "No Data Found!";
    tomorrowsShift.Text = "No Data Found";
}
else
{
    string todayCellRow = ws.Cells[objectRow, 1].Row.ToString();
    string tomorrowCellRow = ws.Cells[objectRow + 1, 1].Row.ToString();
    DateTime todayStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ws.Cells["E" + todayCellRow].Value);
    DateTime todayFinishTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ws.Cells["F" + todayCellRow].Value);
    DateTime tomorrowStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ws.Cells["E" + tomorrowCellRow].Value);
    DateTime tomorrowFinishTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ws.Cells["F" + tomorrowCellRow].Value);
    string tdayShiftS = todayStartTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    string tdayShiftF = todayFinishTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    string tmorShiftS = tomorrowStartTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    string tmorShiftF = tomorrowFinishTime.ToString("HH:mm");

    if (tdayShiftS == "00:00" && tdayShiftF == "00:00")
    {
        todaysShift.Text = "Day Off!";
    }
    else
    {
        todaysShift.Text = tdayShiftS + " - " + tdayShiftF;
    }

    if (tmorShiftS == "00:00" && tmorShiftF == "00:00")
    {
        tomorrowsShift.Text = "Day Off!";
    }
    else
    {
        tomorrowsShift.Text = tmorShiftS + " - " + tmorShiftF;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the starting date where you calculate that 4-week period?

Comment: The year begins on 04/01/2017 which was a Sunday. The spreadsheet starts on a Sunday and finishes on a Saturday 28 days later. As I say, each sheet represents 28 days (4 weeks) worth of shift patterns.

Comment: Are we talking about 1. June 2017 or 6. Januar 2017 (both are not Sunday on my calendar)?

Comment: Sorry, was the 1st of Jan 2017

Comment: Ok, looking forward to 2020 which is the start date of the first 4-week-period in 2020? (I just try to get the calculation rule from you)

Comment: Just to clear things up, this working month begins on 23/04/2017 and ends on 20/05/2017 (sheet starts and finishes). Payday is 26/05/2017.<br>2020 pay period will start on Sunday 29/12/2019

Comment: Are you looking for a solution working only in 2017 or also the next couple of years?

Comment: The next few years ideally. But to be honest, I don't mind editing the code on a yearly basis if need be...

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe it seems that your first 4-week period started on 3 December 2016. Seems strange, but you know better.

Let's call it base date. If you simply subtract base date from 'today', you get a TimeSpan, from which you can calculate number of days, and weeks, and 4-week periods.

```
const DateTime baseDate = new DateTime(2016,12,3);
...

//get rid of time part and calculate days from base date.
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Today - baseDate; 
int weeksDiff = diff.Days / 7;
int periodNum = weeksDiff / 4;
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the int division isn't rounding off wrongly. Trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Flater - integer division rounds down. No problem here. When weeksDiff is 0,1,2,3, periodNum will be 0.

I guess you might want to add 1.

Comment: @SirRufo - I don't understand your comment. There is no 06/01/2017 or Sunday in my post. OP said that 22 April is period 6, and I am working from there.

Comment: The OP posted in comment that the starting date is 06/01/2017 (Sunday) which is edited now to 04/01/2017 (Sunday) and in an additional comment to 01/01/2017 (Sunday)

Comment: Well, this does not sit too well with 22/4 being period 6. 

In any case, I am sure OP is capable of changing baseDate in my code snippet.

Comment: @yu_sha Perfect... Thanks man! Saved me a lot of stress! Haha!

Comment: Lee Davy - no problem, just don't forget to accept an answer, and make sure you get your baseDate right.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a class with all informations to the pay period and constructors to build from period index and date

```
class PayPeriod
{
    const int DAYS_PER_WEEK = 7;
    const int WEEKS_PER_PERIOD = 4;
    static readonly DateTime _startPeriod = new DateTime( 2017, 01, 01 );

    public PayPeriod( int index )
    {
        Index = index;
        StartDate = _startPeriod.Date.AddDays( ( index - 1 ) * DAYS_PER_WEEK * WEEKS_PER_PERIOD );
        EndDate = StartDate.AddDays( DAYS_PER_WEEK * WEEKS_PER_PERIOD - 1 );
    }

    public static PayPeriod FromDate( DateTime date )
    {
        var index = ( date.Date - _startPeriod ).Days / DAYS_PER_WEEK / WEEKS_PER_PERIOD + 1;
        return new PayPeriod( index );
    }

    public int Index { get; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; }
}
```